# navigation drawer hide keyboard when onDrawerOpened

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a fragment with  edittext in it. 
when i click the edittext, the keyboard show up.
the problem is when i open the drawer, the drawer does not hide the keyboard. 
the keyboard is still showing even i switch to another fragment. 
How can i hide the keyboard when i open the drawer.

i try to put

```
InputMethodManager imm = 
                        (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0);
```

and

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

both of it do not hide the keyboard.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use this line of code before opening/closing the slide drawer:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: I always got troubles getting a `WindowToken` from an `EditText` while using `Fragments` (being in `NavigationDrawer` or `ViewPager`). `Activity.getCurrentFocus()` was the one thing I was missing. Many thanks.

Comment: Agreed. Other hideKeyboard() methods used in the DrawerListener  in conjunction with some form of focus tweaking would still somehow show the keyboard when the NavDrawer was opened. THIS was the only variation that worked for me. It basically combines the effort of what I had tried, unsuccessfully, to do separately.

Answer (score 28):

Try this...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ......
   
    //Initialize
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   
    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

}
```

[DrawerListerner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html):

```
 ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    };
```

Comment: hello sir, it gives me a null pointer exception  if (drawer != null) {

            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            hideKeyboard(this);
        }  and i cannot make any changes in ActionBarDrawerToggle in android studio, using appcompatv7 . Please help

Comment: Please check your ActionBarDrawerToggle listener object, if it not implemented properly it may prone to null pointer exception.

Answer (score 9):

Set **drawer listener** is already deprecated you can detect navigation drawer state change using **mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener()** and close keyboard onDrawerStateChange

```
mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        //Called when a drawer's position changes.

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        //Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state.
        //The drawer is interactive at this point.
        // If you have 2 drawers (left and right) you can distinguish 
        // them by using id of the drawerView. int id = drawerView.getId(); 
        // id will be your layout's id: for example R.id.left_drawer            
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        // Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state.
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
        // Called when the drawer motion state changes. The new state will be one of STATE_IDLE, STATE_DRAGGING or STATE_SETTLING.
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `getWindowToken()` must be called from the View that is currently "holding" the keyboard. It is very annoying, I agree with you, but that is how it works.

For example let's say `EditText mEditText` is the object currently in focus receiving the keyboard keystrokes. So then your code would be:

```
 InputMethodManager imm = 
                    (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I create my own Helper class to show or hide keyboard.

Here it is...

```
public static class Helper {

    public static void showKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null) {
            imm.showSoftInput(activity.getCurrentFocus(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    }

    public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null && activity.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

}
```

Call `Helper.showKeyboard(this)` to show the keyboard.
Call `Helper.hideKeyboard(this)` to hide the keyboard.
`this` refers to Activity.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simple best solution i've come up so far.All you gotta do is to create a `InputMethodManager` object. Add a listener to the `DrawerLayout` object and finally 
add the line of code in the following methods `inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);`  and your good to go.

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View view, float v) {
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
        }
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View view) {
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View view) {
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int i) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**If You Used the toggle with drawer then add onDrawerStateChanged manually in your onCreate method**

```
 DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, appToolBar, R.string.Open_Drawer, R.string.Close_Drawer);


        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, appToolBar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
               /* InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        */    }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
              /*  InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
       */     }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                // Called when the drawer motion state changes. The new state will be one of STATE_IDLE, STATE_DRAGGING or STATE_SETTLING.
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

            }
        };




        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);

        toggle.syncState();
```